# Compile with nexe the main process electron js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, electron, nexe

Is it possible to compile the main process of electron `main.js` with some tool? I am using `nexe` to compile the main process `main.js` but it doesn't work.Is there a way to do that?

I am using https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start

Then I use `nexe main.js` to generate a compilation.

Then I modify `package.json` by changing the value of `main.js` to `main.exe`.

Finally `npm start` and I get an error message:

```js
MZ´┐¢


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1004:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:769:28)
    at loadApplicationPackage (C:\Users\Onimac\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:109:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Onimac\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:155:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1004:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
```

Minified main.js code:

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

function createWindow () {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  })
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
})
```

Comment: no, you cannot. main process of electron entrypoint only accepts plain javascript.

Comment: Is there a way to make a call to a file before I call the main.js file? Example: If I have a before.js file that will decrypt the main.js file that will be encrypted with a key, it can only be read by the before.js file That's possible?

Comment: that won't make sense when app is packaged, since you have to ship key to decrypt anyway so it's essentially same as having code visible to anyone.

Comment: It is true. But it would be possible by rebuilding the same electronjs from its source and adding code to the same original language. How can I compile the ElectronJS framework from scratch?

Comment: it is unclear what is your eventual goal to achieve, hard to suggest details. Though, generally, it's not a great idea to rebuild electron whole from scratch and have to rethink application architecture.

Comment: I would like to protect the source code of my ElectronJS app, if I could find the point to read the .asar file from the ElectronJS source code, I could make the .asar encrypted with a password that only the source of ElectronJS knows, when it loads the .asar is decrypted by accessing and finally the app runs. Where do I find in the ElectronJS source code that reading point of the .asar file to make that modification?